# Angular 17 @switch with Enum Constants

Tags: angular, typescript, enums, switch-statement, angular17

I want to use the new angular @switch statement to show different elements based on a Enum.

```
enum State {
  Loading,
  Loaded,
  Error
}

@Component({
...
})
export class MyComponent {
  state: State = State.Loading;
}
```

```
@switch (state) {
  @case (State.Loading) {
    <p>loading</p>
  }
  @case (State.Loaded) {
    <p>loaded</p>
  }
  @case (State.Error) {
    <p>error</p>
  }
}
```

The Problem it seems its not possible to reference the Enum Type inside html directly.

There are a few workarounds.

For example I could use the numbers instead of the Enum constants, but this would defeat the purpose of using a Enum in the first place.

```
@switch (state) {
  @case (0) {
    <p>loading</p>
  }
  @case (1) {
    <p>loaded</p>
  }
  @case (2) {
    <p>error</p>
  }
}
```

Or I could use a Composite type like this:

```
type State = 'Loading' | 'Loaded' | 'Error';
```

Is there a way to make this work with enums or do I need to switch to a different type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every symbol in a template must be accessible from the component.

This means you need to expose the `enum` :

```
@Component({
   ...
})
export class MyComponent {
  state: State = State.Loading;
  State = State; // State: typeof State = State
}
```

See [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/25963) on that topic.

Answer (score 1):

```
type State = 'Loading' | 'Loaded' | 'Error';

@Component({
  // ...
})
export class MyComponent {
  state: State = 'Loading';
}
```

In the template, you can then use the @switch statement with string literals:

```
@switch(state)
{
  @case('Loading') {
    <p>loading</p>
  }
  @case('Loaded') {
    <p>loaded</p>
  }
  @case('Error') {
    <p>error</p>
  }
}
```

By using a composite type with string literals, you can effectively represent the states without directly using enums in the template. This approach allows you to achieve the desired behavior while working within the current capabilities of the Angular template syntax.

It's important to note that the use of string literals in this context provides a way to represent distinct states without resorting to using numeric values directly in the template. While it may involve a shift in the representation of states, it can still serve the purpose of clearly defining and using different states within the template.

Comment: I did not accept your response as the answer, but its probably still my preferred way of doing it. Thanks